# Serializing An Object Into XML Java

Tags: xml-serialization

In C# we use serializer.ToXmlString/FromXmlString. 
Is there any Java equivalent for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you use a javax.xml.transform.Transformer for DOM objects.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(myDocument), new StreamResult(targetFile));
```

For regular java objects you might want to try [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).